# Division by zero error in a code

Tags: php, opencart

```
public function convert($value, $from, $to) {
    if ($from == $to) {
        return $value;
    }

    if (isset($this->lengths[$from])) {
        $from = $this->lengths[$from]['value'];
    } else {
        $from = 0;
    }

    if (isset($this->lengths[$to])) {
        $to = $this->lengths[$to]['value'];
    } else {
        $to = 0;
    }       

    return $value * ($to / $from);
}
```

This code is giving division by zero error on the line "return $value * ($to/$from)" . Can any one debug this .

Comment: Perhaps `$from = 0;` has something to do with it

Comment: `$from` is the only possible candidate for this error

Comment: What input do you have in this function? Are you sure $from is not 0. I mean really sure it's not zero?

Comment: Why not debug it yourself with a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

How about this simple handling of the Result:

```
        public function convert($value, $from, $to) {
            if ($from == $to) {
                return $value;
            }

            if (isset($this->lengths[$from])) {
                //THE RESULT OF THE EXPRESSION BELOW MAY BE NULL OR 0
                //GUARD AGAINST "DIVISION-BY-ZERO" WARNING FAR BELOW 
                //BECAUSE: $a = 0; isset($a) RETURNS TRUE...
                $from = $this->lengths[$from]['value'];
            } else {
                $from = 0;
            }

            if (isset($this->lengths[$to])) {
                $to = $this->lengths[$to]['value'];
            } else {
                $to = 0;
            }

            //HERE: AVOID WARNING/ERROR BEEPERS
            if($from != 0){
                return $value * ($to / $from);          
            }
            return "NaN - Not a Number";
        }
```

On the other Hand, the parameters passed to this Method are not doing anything at all... except for the first 3 Lines:

```
        if ($from == $to) {
                return $value;
        }
```

Otherwise, they have no more use within the code because of your overrides. Did you realize this as well?

Another point of notice & concern should be this: it is conceivable that $to, $from & $value are Numeric. Although, You alone know your Program better than all; i sincerely dare to ask you this:

Is this similar to how you can access data in your $lengths Array:
**$this->lengths[100]['value']**?

Comment: This is what I would have suggested. Your code error is litterally telling you that you're dividing by zero, so you have to build your code to prepare for that. A simple if statement usually does the trick.

Comment: Is this similar to how you can access data in your $lengths Array: $this->lengths[100]['value']?       --  Yes it is similar

Answer (score -1):

you are setting `$form` and `$to` to 0 (ZERO), so if none or one of them condition will not satisfied this would happen `0 / $from` or `$to /0` or `0 / 0` in any case error your are getting is correct.

Comment: You described the problem. Can you please add a solution?

Comment: actually solution depends on what output function should return. and user didn't mentation that, so try to replace 0 with 1,